# Using a variable in Javascript object/json produces compile error

Tags: javascript, json

First time working with javascript and JSON.  Curious why this causes a comiler error:

```
var dataTypes = new function() {
    this.list = "list"; this.boolean = "boolean";
};  

var jsonDataTypes = [
        {dataTypes.list:"Food For Lunch"}
];
```

When this doesn't.

```
var dataTypes = new function() {
    this.list = "list"; this.boolean = "boolean";
};  

var jsonDataTypes = [
        {"Food For Lunch":dataTypes.list}
];
```

Why am I allowed to use a variable for the value but not for the key?

The error is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Missing semicolon
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
     construct(s)
    - Missing semicolon
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
     tokens
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are working with JavaScript objects, not JSON. Objects are a data type in JavaScript, whereas JSON is a data transfer format.

The keys inside object literals must be valid identifiers, strings or numbers, because keys are interpreted *literally*. Identifiers are not allowed to have dots (`.`) and certain other characters in it. See the [specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5) for more information.

As you want to use the value of `dataTypes.list` as key, you have to create the object in two steps:

```
var jsonDataTypes = [{}];
jsonDataTypes[0][dataTypes.list] = "Food For Lunch";
```

or if you want to use it literally, use a string:

```
var jsonDataTypes = [
    {"dataTypes.list": "Food For Lunch"}
];
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the JS syntax. But you can do the following:

```
var jsonDataTypes = [{}];

jsonDataTypes[0][dataTypes.list] = "Food For Lunch";
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript object syntax does not allow for evaluation of the `Key`.  I suppose you *could* do the following:

```
var jsonDataTypes = [];
var obj = {};
obj[dataTypes.list] = "Food For Lunch";
jsonDataTypes.push(obj);
```